# Different color in each bar in telerik bar chart

Tags: model-view-controller, charts, telerik

we want to display the different color for each bar in bar chart.we want to show red color for database value ranges from 0-69,yellow for 70-84,green for 85-100 in the same chart.

Comment: please describe it. we can't write whole code for it.